# js tree create_child, creates sibling not child

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodes, jstree

I use the jstree contextmenu to create new child nodes.
When I do this, jstree creates a sibling of the node I clicked and I need it to create a childnode of that node.

this is my code:

```
ref.create_node(sel, data, "after");
```

sel = parent id

data = childnode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I had to get the last child id of the parent:

```
var lastChild = $("#"+sel).find("li:last-child").attr("id");
```

And then use it as parent for the child node i wanted to create.

```
ref.create_node(lastChild, {"type":"tag", "id":data.id}, "after");
```

I do wonder if there is an more direct way to do this.